# OPEN emp_refcur FOR {plsql variable} giving error

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am novice in plsql development.

I have a problem opening cursor on plsql variable (which has my dynamic SQL query). I am on ORACLE 12 i believe.

Details below:

```
emp_refcur      SYS_REFCURSOR; -- Cursor declaration

component_sql:= 'select * from emp'; -- Base SQL

-- dynamic sql based on business logic
IF SOME_CONDITION THEN
  filters:= ' where DEP IN (''ABC'',''DEF'')';
ELSE
  filters:= ' where age>50';

component_sql:= component_sql||filters; -- appending filter to my base sql

OPEN emp_refcur FOR component_sql; -- opening the cursor
     LOOP
        FETCH emp_refcur INTO result;
            EXIT WHEN emp_refcur%NOTFOUND;
            dbms_output.put_line(result);
     END LOOP;
    CLOSE emp_refcur;
```

Compiling this procedure shown error at line 'OPEN emp_refcur FOR component_sql' and error are

```
Error(90,9): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(90,29): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

I do not want to use bind values like

```
'OPEN emp_refcur FOR p_query_string USING p_deptno, p_sal;'
```

I have tried multiple approaches

```
OPEN emp_refcur FOR ''||component_sql||''; -- This approach is not causing compilation error, but running the procedure resulting 

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

AND

```
OPEN emp_refcur FOR 'select * from emp'||filters; -- This is resulting the error 
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Not sure what i am missing here. Please help.

NOTE: Please ignore if there are any SQL query syntax errors. Because the SQL which i am printing after appending the filters is executing fine and getting results when i run separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with your code and it has no issues. PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type --> This is a syntax error. It has nothing to do with bind variables. What is the declaration for result? I don't see in the snippet.

```
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Cause: An expression has the wrong datatype for the context in which it was found.

Action: Change the datatype of the expression. You might want to use datatype conversion functions.



Declare 
  emp_refcur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  filters varchar2(100);
  component_sql varchar2(100);
  result varchar2(20);

    Begin
    component_sql:= 'select 1 from dual'; -- Base SQL

    -- dynamic sql based on business logic
    IF 1=1 THEN
      filters:= ' UNION ALL SELECT 2 from dual';
    ELSE
      filters:= ' where age>50';
    End if;
    component_sql:= component_sql||filters; -- appending filter to my base sql
    OPEN emp_refcur FOR component_sql ; -- opening the cursor
         LOOP
            FETCH emp_refcur INTO result;
                EXIT WHEN emp_refcur%NOTFOUND;
                dbms_output.put_line(result);
         END LOOP;
        CLOSE emp_refcur;
    END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Valli..
The problem was - i declared 'component_sql' as NVARCHAR2. When i compared with your code i changed it to VARCHAR2 and it WORKED. :-)

Comment: @NewBee95 Happy to help And Welcome. If this is the answer, please accept it as answer